# How does as work in ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

I was writing a function that inserts a integer at the nth spot in a list and I initially wrote

```
 let rec insert x n l =
 match l with
 |[] -> [x]
 | h:: t -> if n = 0 then x :: l else h :: insert x (n-1) t
```

this would throw an error when I tried to add an integer at the end of the list.

```
let rec insert x n l =
match l with
 |[] -> [x]
 |h :: t as l  -> if n = 0 then x :: l else h :: insert x (n-1) t
         _
```

Adding as fixed the problem but I am not sure I fully understand what as is doing and was wondering how else as could be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two bits of code have the same meaning.

I can't see any problem with either one.

To answer your question, `as` is used to give a name to a subpart of a pattern. The pattern `h :: t as l` matches a non-empty list by binding `h` to the head of the list `t` to the tail of the list and `l` to the whole list.

In your example, the new binding for `l` is the same as the original binding (the function parameter). So there's no difference in the meaning of the code.

Here's a session with the first version:

```
        OCaml version 4.03.0

# let rec insert x n l =
    match l with
    | [] -> [x]
    | h :: t -> if n = 0 then x :: l else h :: insert x (n-1) t;;
val insert : 'a -> int -> 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>
# insert 'r' 3 ['o'; 'e'];;
- : char list = ['o'; 'e'; 'r']
# insert 'r' 2 ['o'; 'e'];;
- : char list = ['o'; 'e'; 'r']
# insert 'r' 1 ['o'; 'e'];;
- : char list = ['o'; 'r'; 'e']
# insert 'r' 0 ['o'; 'e'];;
- : char list = ['r'; 'o'; 'e']
```

I don't see any problem adding a value to the end of the list.